# Text Color Transition one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I add transition text colors one by one, just like Vercel's homepage hero?
Below is my code? Like having a delayed start in the transition of the second text.

How can I add transition text colors one by one, just like Vercel's homepage hero to the below code?
Like having a delayed start in the transition of the second text.

```css
 
p{
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 50px;
   animation: Color 4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: Color 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px #F0F0F0;
}

@keyframes Color{
  0%{
    color:#A0D468;
  }
  
  20%{
    color:#4FC1E9;
  }
  
  40%{
    color:#FFCE54;
  }
  
  60%{
    color:#FC6E51;
  }
  
  80%{
    color:#ED5565;
  }
  
  100%{
    color:#AC92EC;
  }
}
```

```html
<p> First Text </p>
<p> Second Text </p>
```

Thank you very much if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: What is this "Vercel's homepage hero" you're referencing?

Comment: oh i mean this https://vercel.com/home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this, I think this is what you are looking for.

```css
p{
font-size:40px;
font-weight:900;
animation:colour 4s infinite;
}

p:nth-of-type(2){
animation-delay:2s;
}
@keyframes colour{
0%{color:black;}
25%{color:black;}
50%{color: green;}
75%{color:black;}
100%{color:black;}
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hi!!</p>
```

But if you want to do it with 3 p tags then :

```css
p{
font-size:40px;
font-weight:900;
animation:colour 6s infinite;
}

p:nth-of-type(2){
animation-delay:2s;
}

p:nth-of-type(3){
animation-delay:4s;
}

@keyframes colour{
0%{color:black;}
35%{color:black;}
50%{color: green;}
65%{color:black;}
100%{color:black;}
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hi!!</p>
<p>Hello</p>
```

Comment: Exactly what I want, but I can't use it with 3 <p> element. :(

Comment: If you want it with 3 <p> tags then you have to change the animation time and animation delay

Comment: I try to play around with that for a while and cannot find out which value work. Anyway Thank you very much.

Comment: I have edited the above answer and it shows the animation with 3 p tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for for to delay the animation then check this ->

```css
p{
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 50px;
   animation: Color 4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: Color 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px #F0F0F0;
}

p:nth-of-type(2){
animation-delay:1s;
}

@keyframes Color{
  0%{
    color:#A0D468;
  }
  
  20%{
    color:#4FC1E9;
  }
  
  40%{
    color:#FFCE54;
  }
  
  60%{
    color:#FC6E51;
  }
  
  80%{
    color:#ED5565;
  }
  
  100%{
    color:#AC92EC;
  }
}
```

```html
<p> First Text </p>
<p> Second Text </p>
```

Comment: thank you, but I want to transition the text color once a time and repeat, like vercel.com's hero banner

Answer (score 0):

Check this sandbox out. This exactly looks like vercel.
Link to Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-hodgkin-6xsy8l?file=/index.html

Here is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="section-process">
      <div class="section-container">
        <div class="process-steps-container container-medium with-padding">
          <div class="process-step-container process-step-1">
            <div class="process-step-title-container">
              <h1 class="process-step-title">Plan</h1>
              <div class="process-step-title-overlay">Plan</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="process-step-container process-step-2">
            <div class="process-step-title-container">
              <h1 class="process-step-title">Design</h1>
              <div class="process-step-title-overlay">Design</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="process-step-container process-step-3">
            <div class="process-step-title-container">
              <h1 class="process-step-title">Develop</h1>
              <div class="process-step-title-overlay">Develop</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the **CSS** type

```
.section-process {
  --gradient-color-1: #ef008f;
  --gradient-color-2: #6ec3f4;
  --gradient-color-3: #7038ff;
  --gradient-color-4: #c9c9c9;
}
.section-process
  .process-steps-container
  .process-step-container
  .process-step-title-container {
  margin-top: -16px;
  position: relative;
}
.section-process
  .process-steps-container
  .process-step-container
  .process-step-title-container
  .process-step-title,
.section-process
  .process-steps-container
  .process-step-container
  .process-step-title-container
  .process-step-title-overlay {
  font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
    "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 156px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
}
.section-process
  .process-steps-container
  .process-step-container
  .process-step-title-container
  .process-step-title-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  padding-right: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
.section-process
  .process-steps-container
  .process-step-container.process-step-1
  .process-step-title-overlay {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    var(--gradient-color-1),
    var(--gradient-color-2)
  );
  animation: animated-gradient-title-1 8s infinite;
}
.section-process
  .process-steps-container
  .process-step-container.process-step-2
  .process-step-title-overlay {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    var(--gradient-color-2),
    var(--gradient-color-3)
  );
  animation: animated-gradient-title-2 8s infinite;
}
.section-process
  .process-steps-container
  .process-step-container.process-step-3
  .process-step-title-overlay {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    var(--gradient-color-3),
    var(--gradient-color-1)
  );
  animation: animated-gradient-title-3 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes animated-gradient-title-1 {
  0%,
  16.667%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.333%,
  83.333% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes animated-gradient-title-2 {
  0%,
  16.667%,
  66.667%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.333%,
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes animated-gradient-title-3 {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66.667%,
  83.333% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Demo:
[image: Demo]